# How to call suspend function from FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: service, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

I need to call suspend function from onMessageRecieved(), but this service doesn't provide a scope. So I don't know from where to call  `job.cancel()`. How to use suspend function in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FirebaseMessagingService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) is a derived class of [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service), so you can use it's `onDestroy()` to cancel your coroutines.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```